# How do I split a string by specific pairing groups?

Tags: java, string, split

I am writing my own JSON parser in Java and I am looking for a way to split a string by a comma or a colon, that are outside `[]`, `{}` or `""` pairs.

I found a [tutorial via Google](https://rjcodeblog.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/regex-to-split-a-string-on-comma-outside-double-quotes/comment-page-1/#comment-186), and it works. The issue is, that it also captures the commas inside those brackets, and I need it to ommit them. I don't know how to edit the regular expression to exclude captured commass from one of these bracket pairs. I tried something like `",(?=([^\"\\{\\[]*\"[^\"\\}\\]]*\")*[^\"]*$)"`, but it doesn't work. It messes it up even more. The same also applies to the colon separation, which is used in separation of key and value of a JSON object.

Is there a way to combine the `""`, `{}` and `[]` pairs together in the regex in such way that it works? Sorry if I look like a lame, but I really can't figure out how the regex should look like.

BTW, this is a code snippet I want to use it in:

```java
public class JavaJSON {
    private HashMap<String, Object> content;

    // Constructors

    /**
     * Create new empty JSON object
     */
    public JavaJSON() {
        this.content = new HashMap<>();
    }
    // ...

    /**
     * Parse a JSON string to a JSON object
     *
     * @param JSON JSON string to be converted to JSON object
     * @return JSON object from given string
     */
    public static JavaJSON parse(@NotNull String JSON) {
        if (!JSON.startsWith("{") || !JSON.endsWith("}")) return null;
        // If this is not a valid JSON string, return nothing.

        JavaJSON output = new JavaJSON();

        String content = JSON.substring(1, JSON.length() - 1);
        if (content.length() == 0) return output;    // if empty, return an empty JSON object

        // Regex literals
        String commaSeparated = ",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)";  // TODO: Change commaSeparated to capture any {} [] "" pair group
        String colonSeparated = ":(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)";  // TODO: Change colonSeparated to capture any {} [] "" pair group

        String[] tokens = content.split(commaSeparated);

        if (tokens.length == 0) return null;
        // Don't know exactly if this is going to happen, but better be sure

        for (String token : tokens) {
            String rawToken = token.trim();

            if (rawToken.length() == 0) return null;
            // Omitted comma, extra comma, etc. = JSON error

            String[] mapToken = rawToken.split(colonSeparated);
            if (mapToken.length < 2 || mapToken.length > 2) return null;
            // Expected format = {"foo": "bar"}; format isn't valid

            String mapKey = mapToken[0].trim();
            String mapValue = mapToken[1].trim();

            if (!mapKey.startsWith("\"") || !mapKey.endsWith("\"")) return null;
            // Key must be a string

            String rawMapKey = mapKey.substring(1, mapKey.length() - 1);    // get quote-less variant
            if (rawMapKey.length() == 0) return null;
            // Key must not be empty

            // check errors
            if (mapValue.startsWith("{") && !mapValue.endsWith("}")) return null;
            // Not a valid JSON object
            if (mapValue.startsWith("[") && !mapValue.endsWith("]")) return null;
            // Not a valid JSON array
            if (mapValue.startsWith("\"") && !mapValue.endsWith("\"")) return null;
            // Not a valid string

            // get value object
            Object rawMapValue;

            // parse value object
            if (mapValue.startsWith("\"") && mapValue.endsWith("\"")) {
                rawMapValue = mapValue.substring(1, mapValue.length() - 1);
            } else if (mapValue.startsWith("{") && mapValue.endsWith("}")) {
                rawMapValue = parse(mapValue);
            } else if (mapValue.startsWith("[") && mapValue.endsWith("]")) {
                rawMapValue = parseArray(mapValue);
            } else {
                try {
                    rawMapValue = Long.parseLong(mapValue);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    try {
                        rawMapValue = Double.parseDouble(mapValue);
                    } catch (Exception f) {
                        return null;
                        // Not a valid number
                    }
                }
            }

            output.update(rawMapKey, rawMapValue);
        }

        return output;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: If you are writing a parser for fun, I would encourage you to write a proper parser instead of using regex, since regexes cannot parse all json valid inputs. If you are writing a parser for profit, then you really shouldn't.

Comment: @emilianogc It's not for profit, just for fun. Just wanna my own. I know there is already one, but I'm kind of nit picking and want my own stuff :D How does a proper parser look according to you?

Comment: @emilianogc Oh, and it's not just a parser, but a full JSON object. I uploaded it to [GitHub](https://github.com/Polda18/JavaJSON/blob/master/src/io/github/polda18/java/JavaJSON.java), I don't want to keep my creations just for myself...

Comment: Okay, I tried separate pairs (`[]`, `{}`), and I guess I really don't know how to do that, because it didn't work :(

Comment: So I found some [info](http://cogitolearning.co.uk/2013/04/writing-a-parser-in-java-the-tokenizer/) about writing own parser, I guess. I'll give it a shot...

Comment: Or, [this one](https://dzone.com/articles/parsing-any-language-in-java-in-5-minutes-using-an). I'll go with this one...

Comment: So I found out about `antlr`, and that quite got me [stumped even more than regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54240213/how-can-i-define-my-own-parser-object-definition-in-java-using-antlr). How am I supposed to use this stuff?